# mysql doesnot support nested column change

Tags: mysql

```
    ALTER TABLE `paylist` 
  DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
  ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`), 
  CHANGE COLUMN payment_method payment_method varchar(20) NULL AFTER supplier_id, 
  CHANGE COLUMN supplier_id supplier_id varchar(32) NULL AFTER property_number;
```

the above statment gives an error: Error : Unknown column 'supplier_id' in 'paylist'. but they can be run in separte statment .e.g.

```
 ALTER TABLE `paylist`  CHANGE COLUMN payment_method payment_method varchar(20) NULL AFTER supplier_id;
```

and

```
ALTER TABLE `paylist`  CHANGE COLUMN  supplier_id supplier_id varchar(32) NULL AFTER property_number;
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Nice of you to inform us of the way MYSQL works.

Comment: MySQL works fine [by the way](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/52f8de), it seems original table didn't have the column `supplier_id` so `... AFTER supplier_id;` failed